# How to make an API call and display it in a Table With React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to make a component that will display API data in a table. The API is hosted on heroku at: https://protravelete-api.herokuapp.com/getAllEvents Here is a sample of the format that the API is returning in case that helps:

```
[
{"date":"2020-10-16","distance":5,"email":"sampleemail1@gmail.com","location":"sampletown1","name":"testperson","pace":"7","time":"16:00"},
{"date":"2020-10-18","distance":15,"email":"sampleemail2@gmail.com","location":"sampletown2","name":"testperson2","pace":"6","time":"19:00"}
]
```

The current component code is copied and pasted below:

```
import React from 'react';
import './Table.css';

export class ShowAllEvents extends React.Component {


    constructor(props) {
       super(props)
       this.state = {
            events: []
       }
    }

    componentWillMount() {
      const url = "https://protravelete-api.herokuapp.com/getAllEvents"; 
      fetch(url)
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(content => content) 
      .then(events => {
         console.log(events)
         this.setState(events)
      })
  
      .then(console.log(this.state.events))
    }

 
    renderTableHeader() {
       let header = Object.keys(this.state.events[0])
       return header.map((key, index) => {
          return <th key={index}>{key.toUpperCase()}</th>
       })
    }
 
    renderTableData() {
       return this.state.events.map((events, index) => {
          const {date, distance, email, location, name, pace, time } = events //destructuring
          return (
             <tr key={name}>
                <td>{name}</td>
                <td>{location}</td>
                <td>{date}</td>
                <td>{time}</td>
                <td>{distance}</td>
                <td>{pace}</td>
                <td>{email}</td>
             </tr>
          )
       })
    }
 
    render() {
       return (
          <div>
             <h1 id='title'>All Upcomming Events</h1>
             <table id='events'>
                <tbody>
                   <tr>{this.renderTableHeader()}</tr>
                   {this.renderTableData()}
                </tbody>
             </table>
          </div>
       )
    }
 }
```

Anyone out there who can help? I'm sure my problems are just stupid mistakes, I am very new to using React, so my code is pretty messy.

Comment: Hey Glennonr,

Are you getting data back from your API call? 
It looks like your should be doing .then(response => response.json()) instead of .text to unstringify your response.

Are you getting any errors?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You forgot to `return` the response in the second the `thenable` chain, which return undefined to third `then`. `events` become undefined. Try like this.

UPDATED: Use `componentDidMount` for AJAX calls, [recommended by React](https://reactjs.org/docs/faq-ajax.html#where-in-the-component-lifecycle-should-i-make-an-ajax-call).

```
  componentDidMount() {
    const url = "http://127.0.0.1:5000/getAllEvents"; 
    fetch(url)
    .then(response => response.json())
    // .then(content => content) // This can be optional if you don't map the response
    .then(events => {
       console.log(events)
       this.setState({ events })
    })
  }
```

```
renderTableHeader() {
  if (!this.state.events.length) return null
  const header = Object.keys(this.state.events[0]) // Earlier, you're getting error here
  return header.map((key, index) => {
    return <th key={index}>{key.toUpperCase()}</th>
  })
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the heads up, I changed the componentWillMount function to reflect yours, however I am still getting an error: TypeError: Cannot convert undefined or null to object, in the renderTableHeader function

Comment: That's because `renderTableHeader `, you're doing `let header = Object.keys(this.state.events[0])` which is undefined before getting data. That's why you're seeing that error

Comment: Updated my answer, Check once.

Answer (score 0):

Use response.json() instead of response.text

```
 componentWillMount() {
  const url = "http://127.0.0.1:5000/getAllEvents"; 
  fetch(url)
  .then(response => response.json())
  .then(contents => console.log(contents))
  .then(events => this.setState(events))

  .then(console.log(this.state.events))
}
```